# How to customize submenus isn wordpress theme

Tags: menus, sub-menu, theme-customizer

I have a wordpress theme and in the header.php file it is displaying menus through this line :

```
wp_nav_menu( 'theme_location=menu_2&menu_id=nav&container=&fallback_cb=menu_2_default');
```

Now if I hover some menu item, it displays submenus items. I just want to change the layout of the submenu items section or div , but I can't find any html of submenus. I need help in this

Submenu is appearing in the form of dropdown , I want to change this into a different style like this one :

http://opinion.inquirer.net/

Comment: Dropdown - as in when you hover over the menu item, the sub-menu appears?

Comment: Yes , I want to change this into the menu in the above link

Comment: As-written, this question is **out of scope** for WPSE, as it is purely a CSS question. The `wp_nav_menu()` provides menu/sub-menu HTML markup output. That markup just needs to be styled to your needs.

Comment: Hammad, in the link you gave there are no sub menus. Each top level link goes to a new sub domain. Each sub domain has two menus. One for the top level menus and another specific to that sub domain.

Answer (score 0):

The submenu markup is generated through the [wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu) function.  You will not find anywhere a "template" or "file" that allows you to modify the markup.

What is it that you want to change? If you can explain that, we may be able to provide alternate solutions for you.

Finally, if you really must change the markup that is generated, you can write a [custom menu walker](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function), but that requires some knowledge and skill with PHP.

Comment: Submenu is appearing in the form of dropdown , I want to change this into a different style like this one :

http://opinion.inquirer.net/

Comment: @HammadShahid Can you point us at a URL to look at for the current menu?

Comment: Yes , top menu on the inquirer page. and for the current menu

http://theme-dutch.com/how-to-set-up-a-submenu-in-wordpress/

Please notice the top (main) menus of both websites

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to accomplish this with CSS. `wp_nav_menu` adds a lot of [classes to each menu item](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Menu_Item_CSS_Classes), so you should be able to use relative positioning on the menu container. Then absolutely position `ul.sub-menu` to the left and bottom of your menu container. If you make sure to use `display:none` on all sub-menus and then `display:block` with the current sub-menu, it theoretically should work without having to deal with an advanced Walker.